# Android - AutoCompleteTextView dynamic updating issue

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

well i'm trying to update the autoCompleteTextview ArrayAdapter dynamiclly each time text changed by using TextWathcer.

every time text changed there is an http request in a new AsyncTask and in the callback from the async task (onPostExecute) i call clear() from the adapter and adding new items to him and then call notifyDataSetChanged.
Unfortunately the auto complete drop down is never shown..

please, where do i go worng?!

here is the code:

```
AutoCompleteTextView acCountry = (AutoCompleteTextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
final ArrayAdapter<RMAutoComplete.ListItem> countriesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<RMAutoComplete.ListItem>(this.context,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
acCountry.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 1)
                {
                    new AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RMAutoComplete.ListItem>>(){

                        @Override
                        protected List<ListItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
                            List<ListItem> l = null;
                            try {
                                l = location.getCountryData(params[0]);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG,"error when getCountryData",e);
                            }
                            return l;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(List<ListItem> countries) {
                            countriesAdapter.clear();
                            if (countries != null)
                                for (ListItem listItem : countries) {
                                    countriesAdapter.add(listItem);
                                }
                            countriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }.execute(s.toString());
                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        }
    );
```

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common mistake : Did you set the adapter to `acCountry` at all?

Comment: thanks man! i can't believe this was my mistake.. 3 hours!! common mistake. :)